# I need a regex statement that matches something similar to PHPDocs

Tags: regex

I know this isn't an easy task, But will be very appreciated if someone can help.

I need a regex statement that matches this:

```
/**
**  <summary>Ahmed
**  Gasser
**  Anas
**  Mohd</summary>
**  <param name="PARAM_NAME">PARAM_EXPLAIN</param>
**  <param name="bla">what
**  are
**  you doing</param>
**  <returns>
**      asdnasgdiuasgdiygas digasidgiaysgd iagsdiyas gd
**  </returns>
**  <remarks>
**      dihasoudausod uiasgdiuags idugasidasd kuasgud
**  </remarks>
*/
```

Basically I want it to just match any text that start with /** and end with a */
And each line inside it must start with a **

I hope you get what I mean, if not please reply and I will do my best again to explain my problem.
It will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
/(\/\*\*[\s\S])(\*\*.*[\s\S])+(\*\/)/
```

I used `[\s\S]` instead of `/s` modifier to ensure that every line will start with `**`. You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/mU8mX2/1). But, if it is not really necessary, you can also use [this](https://regex101.com/r/nC2cK4/1) one:

```
/(\/\*\*.)(\*\*.*.+)(\*\/)/s
```